# Solving a non-convex quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP)

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I am trying to solve following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x\in\Re^{n}} & ~x^\top H x + f^\top x + \sqrt{x^\top R x}\\
\text{s.t.} & ~Ax<b  
\end{aligned},
\end{equation}
where $f<0$, $H$ is a positive definite matrix and $R$ is a diagonal positive definite matrix. By letting $z:=\sqrt{x^\top R x}~$ and $~p:=\begin{bmatrix} z & x^\top\end{bmatrix}$, original problem becomes a nonconvex QCQP problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{p} & ~p^\top \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & H\end{bmatrix} p + \begin{bmatrix}1 & f^\top\end{bmatrix} p\\
\text{s.t.} & ~\begin{bmatrix}0 & A\end{bmatrix} p<b \\
~p^\top &\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & R\end{bmatrix} p \leq 0
\end{aligned},
\end{equation}
Because a general non-convex QCQP problem is NP-hard, I am wondering, is there anyway I could solve this problem? If so, is there any solvers recommended? Many thanks!

Comment: Why transform a convex problem into a non-convex one?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hi, Because I am not sure how to deal with square root of quadratic term. Could you tell me the best way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a numerical solution or an analytical solution?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hi, do you mind to provide both? I would like  learn more about this kind of problem, many thanks!

Comment: The square-root term can be rewritten as $\| R^{\frac12} x \|_2$. It's not for me to provide a numerical solution, it is for (software) solvers. An analytical solution, if it exists, would require time that I don't have.